# How to remove a div with particular id containing particular text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

```
if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
    $.each(function(){
        if ($('#result').has("Apartment")) {
            $('#result').remove();
        }
    })
}
```

I want that if I uncheck a checkbox then the div having id="result" should be deleted which contains the text "Apartment". Currently this logic is not working for me.

Comment: if ($('#result').text() === 'Apartment)

Comment: you should be using $('#result').text()==="Apartment" in your if condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#checkboxId').change(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#result:contains(Apartment)').remove();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/msuL0yta/157/)

Comment: jQuery objects does not have a [traverse function](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) `.contains()` you must use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: Ok thanks for enlightening me. I have updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
 $('#checkboxId').change(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            if($('#result').text().indexOf("mystring")>-1) {
                $('#result').remove();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation on what the code is doing

Answer (score 0):

> particular **id** containing particular text?

```
if( $('elementselector').attr('id').indexOf('Apartment')>-1) { ..... }
```

unless there is some new JQ method out there

*( note - elements must have an ID, or check has ID first etc .. )*

Comment: *div having id="result" should be deleted which contains the text "Apartment"* OP wants to check the content of `#result`

Comment: Look at your question title, I gave you the code for that .. if not what you need, hey ho

Comment: Not my question, the title says the same thing. OP wants to check if the `<div id="result">` contains the text `"Apartment"`, if it does it should be removed.

Comment: cool, just a fly by lunch break throw in answer. Hope you get there

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/bg82uw8s/

```
var IsCheck;
var txt = $("#result").text();
$("#chk").change(function () {
IsCheck = $("#chk").is(":checked");
if (!IsCheck) {
    if (txt === 'Apartment') {
        $("#result").remove();
    }
  }
});
```